# Contour Map Failure

Tags: matplotlib, maps, contour

I am trying to make contour maps with a Latitude, Longitude, and a value that is not elevation for my Master's project. I really like the contour plot of irregularly spaced data in matplotlib, but just can't make it work for my data! I get how it generally works. I have over 600 coordinates.

SEE:
https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/images_contours_and_fields/irregulardatagrid.html

I have a data frame and just need it to plot some points and those nice contour lines. Please save me! I am a noob. I bet this is super easy for one of you matplotlib pros. Here is what I have:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.tri as tri
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv('BI_LT_475_South_Carolina.csv')

Lon = df.iloc[:,0] 
Lat = df.iloc[:,1] 
CSR = df.iloc[:,2]    # What I want to plot instead of elevation.
```

The csv. looks like this:
[Longitude, Latitude, and CSR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SvLKm.png)

Comment: Without the code you tried, nor seeing how the data looks like, it is very hard to guess what is going wrong. Please try to create a [minimal viable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Clearly, the linked code is part of the matplotlib documentation during many years, and well tested.

Comment: Okay, this is my first question ever. I hope this update is enough!

Comment: What did you try? What went well? What went wrong? How did it look like? If the data is irregularly spaced, you could try out `plt.tricontourf(Lon, Lat, CSR)`.

Comment: That's it! I was missing the "plt." part! Write: plt.tricontour(Lon, Lat, CSR) and I will give you the answer. The documentation really confused me with their two different ways and graphs. I was trying to do the uniform grid creation. Like I said, I am a noob and just wanted the tricontour or tricontourf to work.